# Preg_Replace using Alphanumeric Strings

Tags: php, preg-replace

Right now, I have a preg_replace query which only works with numbers. I am sure I didn't restrict it to just numbers, any help?
**Code For Preg_Replace**

```
viewedResult = preg_replace('/#!(\d{1,4})/', '<a href="updateMooring.php?Number2=${1}&id='. $id .'">${1}</a>', $viewedResult);
```

**String required to be replaced** 
012A

Answer (score 1):

`\d` means 'digit'. If you need more, try with character sets like `[0-9A-Z]`.

Comment: Ah, That worked perfectly. I will accept your answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include lowercase and uppercase `a-z`, `0-9` and underscore (`_`), you can use *word character*.

```
preg_replace('/#!(\w{1,4})/', $str);
```